# From ng-repeat in <tr> not accepting parameter in custom filter

Tags: angularjs

In my application I am iterating array with ng-repeat and showing values in tabuler format. Now I want to pass an custom filter which should take an argument from iterated array.
I am doing it in below way:

```
<tr   ng-repeat="arrList in records.actualList|geneFilter:arrList.selectedArr">
```

'selectedArr' is an under 'actualList' and records is the parent array.

Now in my custom filter:

```
"use strict";
var portalApp = angular.module('filter', []);
portalApp.filter('geneFilter', function() {
    return function(input,changedArr){
        var out=[];
        var selectedArr='';
        console.log('changed Arr::'+changedArr);

        return selectedArr;

    }
});
```

In custom filter I am always getting changed arr value as 'undefined'.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very curious about how it should work at all!

we have **cyclic dependency**, here. This is a reason why you get `undefined`

`arrList.selectedArr` is a result of what you return in your filter that should be `return out` and not `return selectedArr`

```
<tr ng-repeat="arrList in records.actualList|geneFilter:arrList.selectedArr">
```

Let's try to describe what we have:

I filter `records.actualList` by custom filter named `geneFilter` that receives as argument the result of filter - `arrList`, a.e.  `arrList.selectedArr` based on filtered data

---

This is how I see it to make it work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in records.actualList|geneFilter:types">
```

and

```
portalApp.filter('geneFilter', function() {
    return function(input,someTypes){
        var out=[];

        angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
          if(someTypes == "some info") {
             out.push(item);
           }        
       });

        return out;
    }
});
```

- here `input` is actually `records.actualList`
- out - an array as result, returned from the filter.
  So you can write your own condition how to filter it

Comment: Actually I want to pass that selectedArr array to the filter as second argument. How could I passed that array to my custom filter?

Comment: You can not pass it because it is a result of the filter, your `out` array. You take it from `arrList`

Comment: Actualy ,I want the 2nd parameter in my filter should be Dynamic. You are taken it as types and static value. Actualy based on dropdown selection I want to show show/hide <tr> thatswhy I am passing my ngmodel and it was inside my ngreapeat array.

Comment: so you want something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0LMJzUiJy0NO9Hk0oWt?p=preview&preview. You need a second ng-repeat

Comment: Sry for the late comment. My data was dynamic and your solutions help me to do auto refresh Thanks.